# What's the formula of SNR (Signal to Noise Ratio) to dipole antenna array (eg, LOFAR) look like?

Tags: error-analysis, signal-processing, antennas, telescopes, noise

It was wellknown that the SNR of **single** **dish** telescope reads
$$s/n=\frac{P_s}{P_n}=\frac{P_{s}}{T_n}\sqrt{\frac{t}{B}},$$
where $P_s$ is the collected power, $T_n$ the noise temperature, $t$ the measure time and $B$ the bandwidth. When it comes to the array of **multiple dish** telescopes, like [SKAO](https://www.skao.int/en), that will change to
$$s/n=\frac{P_s}{\sqrt N P_{n,signal}}$$
where $N$ indicates the number of telescopes.

Recently, I meet across with [LOFAR](https://www.astron.nl/telescopes/lofar/), an telescope project with many stations that each consists of multiple **dipole antennas**. So, does it appropriate for me to treat the SNR of it like that of SKAO?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can give me some guide or direct-related reference.

Comment: References: LOFAR NOISE CALCULATOR https://support.astron.nl/ImageNoiseCalculator/sens.php ; LOFAR (DIPOLE) SENSITIVITY CALCULATIONS https://science.astron.nl/telescopes/lofar/lofar-system-overview/observing-modes/lofar-imaging-capabilities-and-sensitivity/

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks for reminding！

Comment: Also at: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51817/whats-the-formula-of-snr-signal-to-noise-ratio-to-dipole-antenna-array-eg-l